# Ambiguities of the Hubbard-Stratonovich decoupling

Tags: condensed-matter, field-theory, path-integral, superconductivity

Consider an interacting fermionic theory on some lattice $\Lambda$ with action
$$
\mathcal{S}[\bar{\psi},\psi] = \int_{0}^{\beta} \mathrm{d}\tau \sum_{i\in \Lambda} \sum_{\sigma = \left\{ \uparrow,\downarrow\right\} } \bar{\psi}_{i\sigma}(\tau)\left( \partial_{\tau} + \varepsilon(-\mathrm{i} \boldsymbol{\nabla}) \right) \psi_{i\sigma}(\tau) -V \sum_{ i \in \Lambda } \bar{\psi}_{i\uparrow} \psi_{i\uparrow} \bar{\psi}_{i\downarrow} \psi_{i\downarrow}. 
$$
Now, suppose I want to do a Hubbard-Stratonovich decoupling of the interaction, with the purpose of describing the orders of the theory.
I could choose to decouple in the channel corresponding to $\langle\bar{\psi}_{i\sigma}\psi_{i\sigma}\rangle =: \rho_{i\sigma}$ or the one corresponding to $\langle \bar{\psi}_{i\uparrow} \bar{\psi}_{i\downarrow} \rangle =: \bar{\Delta}_{i}$, ultimately furnishing a description of either charge fluctuations or superconducting order in the system.

However, suppose I write
\begin{align}
\mathcal{S}_{\mathrm{int}}[\bar{\psi},\psi] &=  -V \int \mathrm{d}\tau\sum_{ i \in \Lambda } \bar{\psi}_{i\uparrow} \psi_{i\uparrow} \bar{\psi}_{i\downarrow} \psi_{i\downarrow} \\
&= - \lambda V \int \mathrm{d}\tau \sum_{ i \in \Lambda } (\bar{\psi}_{i\uparrow} \psi_{i\uparrow})(\bar{\psi}_{i\downarrow} \psi_{i\downarrow}) - (1-\lambda)V \int \mathrm{d}\tau\sum_{ i \in \Lambda } (\bar{\psi}_{i\uparrow} \bar{\psi}_{i\downarrow})( \psi_{i\downarrow} \psi_{i\uparrow})
\end{align}
and constrain $\lambda \in (0,1)$, and decompose each of the interactions simultaneously in the channels indicated by the parentheses.
Upon performing the usual Hubbard-Stratonovich decoupling in both these channels, and subsequently integrating out the fermions, I obtain a coupled theory of the $\rho$ and $\Delta$ order parameters.
At the mean-field level, minimising this effective action yields two coupled gap equations for $\rho$ and $\Delta$, but with $\lambda$ being essentially a free parameter constraining these equations.

**Question:** What is the interpretation of the $\lambda$ parameter? Clearly, which of the orders will dominate in the system depends on the choice of $\lambda$, so it apparently has a physical meaning. However, the way it was introduced bears little resemblance of anything physical.

**Related:** [Hubbard-Stratonovich Transformation: Success, Failure and Cure](https://hagenkleinert.de/documents/articles/391.pdf)

Comment: I am not sure about using $\lambda V$ and $(1-\lambda)V$ for the two channels. This is somehow arbitrary, because you are assigning different weights to different interaction channels. I would use $V$ for both channels instead, so you still get a coupled theory with two gap equations for $\rho$ and $\Delta$, but with no arbitrary parameter $\lambda$.

Comment: Well, using $V$ for both channels implies that you somehow double the original interaction, which is wrong. The purpose of introducing $\lambda$ is that it seemingly allows for simultaneously treating the fluctuations in two equivalent channels.

Comment: I don't know, apparently it is correct to assign $V$ to all the channels, but I am not 100% sure. I am looking at Altland & Simons - "Condensed Matter Field Theory"(chapter 5, page 247) as a reference, if you wish to take a look

Comment: What Altland discusses is the decomposition of an interaction into *inequivalent* channels. In that case, they are of course additive. The two channels I refer to are obviously equivalent.